# I have seen it all the time

Tags: grammar

> A lot of people think this president is a liar. **I have seen it all the
> time.** They go on social media promoting conspiracy theories about
> him being a sockpuppet of the Soviets.

I am not sure, but "I have seen it all the time" doesn't sound grammatical or idiomatic. Is there anything you would fix?

Comment: It's informal language, and the writer seems to be confusing **I see it all the time** with **I have seen it often/a lot**.

Comment: Source of the quote please.  This looks very odd as Soviets haven't existed since the 1980s and social media only started this century... So social media theories about the Soviets is an odd combination.

Comment: It sounds like a FB post. Don’t try to learn grammar from social media.

Comment: In informal speech, I think this is fine.

Comment: Could you tell me why it's incorrect exactly?